# Java How to define a fundamental operation in a recursive method?

Tags: java, recursion, conceptual

In a recursive method, we will have to set up some base cases. Can we define these base cases as the fundamental operations of the method? As far as I know, fundamental operations are the core functions of the method, which means every time the method is running must pass through these functions. (Please let me know if I am wrong)

Another question is if I got a if statement in the base cases, for example,

if (a != b && b != c){}

Will it be count as 1 or 2 fundamental operations? Cause it is checking 2 part of things:  a != b and  b != c in a single if statement.

This is quite confused.

One more thing is : I am not sure will this kind of code is suitable or not:

Recursive method()

Base case:

XXXXXXX
XXXXXXX
XXXXXXX

Recursive case:

// Should I move this part to the base case?

```
if(conditions){

    return (Recursive method() || Recursive method());
```

// ********************************************************

```
    else if(conditions){

         do something;

    return Recursive method();
```

Cause I think base cases are just used to defined a exact value when meeting the conditions. Therefore I leave this part in the recursive case. I am just not so sure about this.

I am not asking for answer for coursework, just to ensure the concept is correct or not. So I didn't put my algorithm on here. Sorry if this makes you cant understand my question. I will try my best to explain.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide the definitions of `fundamental operation` and `base case`?

Comment: Wiki said "base case breaks the chain of recursion, it is sometimes also called the "terminating case"."

Comment: fundamental operation is the core of a function

Comment: From your definition, you have the example in the question wrong. Your example does not have a `base case` because the recursion is never stopped ;-)

Comment: jso, would you mind to explain a little bit more?

Comment: Spent some time looking for the source of your definitions but without any success.. without that, the answer is actually full of assumptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the definitions provided, a *base case* or *terminating case* is a condition which stops the recursion calls.

The definition of a *fundamental operation* is a bit unclear from the question and I am honestly getting lost in here. But from my understanding it's or it should be a set of operations which are done in a function regardless the *base case*. Link to the definition would help!

Let's have a short example:

```
/**
 * Let's assume the result is not obvious here regardless it's a nth triangular number.
 * Added there a System.out though.
 */
public void calc(int i) {
    System.out.println(i);

    if (i == 0)
        return 0;
    return i + calc(i - 1);
}
```

The only case how to stop the recursion evaluating the first condition `if (i == 0)` to `true`. Meaning that this condition represents the *base case*. When `i` has any other value than zero, the recursion continues.

In the example, the only operation which is done regardless the outcome of the method is printing the value `i`. Thus that's the only *fundamental operation* of the method. (Based on the definition, an evaluation of a condition might and might not be considered an operation since it's not changing any value nor has any side effects, like printing.)

> Can we define these base cases as the fundamental operations of the method?

Generally no, as these represent different situations. The first one defines a case when recursion is stopped and the second one what's always done. Thus if you combine them, you end up with a function which always stops the recursion.

For the following case they could be the same though.

```
public void calc(int i) {
    return i + 1;
}
```